# Redhat 8.4 Java Swing web -- components are not visible, but do exist

Tags: java, swing, spring-mvc, redhat, java-web-start

We are running some new software that is java-based and are trying to run it on Redhat 8.4. The vendor claims that they have it running on Ubuntu, but I have not been able to do the same. The application runs fine via java thin-client, but the web application exhibits strange behavior: after logging in, most of the content except for menus, is just blank. The content is there because mousover works and I can click on things and see the activity in the logs from the clicks, but the content is not visible.

We are running

- jre-1.8.0_101
- Webswing version 2.4
- Chrome 94.0.4606
- X-Atmosphere-Framework 2.3.1
- RedHat 8.4 (I've installed several recommended libraries to include, xorg, Xvfb, and X11 to name a few. I create a Xvfb window and make it available via ENV variable before running the application).

I've tried on multiple OS (MacOS, Windows, Linux) using multiple browsers (Edge, Chrome, Safari, Firefox) and always get the same result. Interestingly, when inspecting the components, everything that is not visible seems to be rendering via canvas. However, I have not been successful in digging into the canvas components with any tools as of yet.

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the source code as it's software we have purchased, but I'm hoping someone has seen something like this before and I can help the devs look in the right place or I can correct whatever may be wrong with my setup. Happy to provide more info where I can. Nothing in the wrapper.log or stdout.log lends any guidance as to what could be going wrong.

Does anyone know what webswing/swing canvas web application components are needed to run successfully on Redhat 8.4? Any other advice or suggestions welcome.

Comment: can u post pdf?

Comment: yes haf posted on yahoo answers thread check there plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to solve the problem by using xpra and Xdummy (https://xpra.org/repos/CentOS/xpra.repo) instead of using xvfb.

Comment: ur rught it hard to log in with java !!! i have downlod fast support can you check micro soft code??? `ÅGªÇÄwU?R±Äüåao/¸à
ºBšÎàšRîX± º‚U5ÌPß,RD¤Œý:šÓàÀÂà))’V«o7äÕ7€…ü/YnùáX¬@b\‰©08‹š/Pnù¢ÂàB˜,VzO×glÐ~'ûý«8ÝlMt³òÛçèfýœ‹Ó±ÖDÇÊzl¥cÍ2ýÁ1fØü¹ù6VÙ!ÝÑ(äPZ‰cóÌÅ:l¾ÀØ*ûš<63¶ÖÄØ*ŒîjzO¨)ÿMÔoÖqÆÖ¾©ó#(H\ÏØj«5€…•Î\
æ¡*:s(^Yutæª`"|ÎßÄmµ¾ûšQ÷“Šá)—>ø>ÀŒöîðÍäi 3Ü®vï‰Æ·•¶^OcËZü0˜X‘Ñ iôQã„¡ufƒ‘!iÌ¸Ç Ck"E*†¤ÕÆ¢ÍÜ`©öÁä:Ï™kJÌCQµYÉÏ„bTû`].Õ>,ý™ÚsšO×>ÄÙUëL:,|%d€lüãìªu×´\àñ.hXAÏ+Î®Z»*^ÈKZ-²XeˆàÄ®šQåø¦ë 
$†·â°¢ë Z-¼’Q×A”b|¤èrbˆ`